# How to deploy a subdirectory of git repo to elastic beanstalk

Tags: django, git, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm fairly new to elastic beanstalk. It was not obvious to me that committing to git was required for deploying, but now I've found in the docs that it uses `git archive` behind the scenes to make a zip that gets deployed.

How can I deploy a subdirectory of a large project only; without uploading the entire contents of the repo?

Say I have a structure like:

```
git-repo/
    mobile/
        ios/...
        android/...
    assets/...
    django-app/
        .ebextensions
        manage.py
        site/...
        ...
```

I want to deploy just `django-app` and below.

Ideally I'd avoid using subtrees, and avoid other scripts (but scripts would be okay if `eb deploy` has a way to automate them).

Comment: Have you considered multiple repositories arranged as submodules? Or do you want to avoid that as well?

Comment: I thought that was subtrees (though I could be missing some nuance there). I want it to be "clone, change, commit, deploy" for other devs, so loads of stepping in and checking out nested layers of stuff is kinda annoying (I'll just set up multiple repos in that case)

Comment: I would also like to know how to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have installed and set up the [EB CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install.html) you can create a script to zip your django-app/ folder and then deploy the resulting artefact:

1. Create a folder in your project root called .ebextensions and inside this folder create a file called config.yml with the following basic contents:

   deploy:
     artifact: "deploy.zip"

(note the spacing is very important in a yml file, "deploy" should be in the first column, "artifact" in a secod (tab spaced) column)

2. Create a deploy.sh script in your project root with the following:

   git archive --format=zip HEAD:django-app/ > deploy.zip;
   eb deploy;

Note: this works very well on Mac and Linux, I've had issues in the past with Windows because of spaces in the user folder structure on Windows.

Comment: Doesn't answer how to do it from github

Comment: No this is specifically how to do it using the CLI and git. Github Actions has a number of options, this is a simple option that largely does the same thing: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/beanstalk-deploy

Comment: When I use this method I receive an error that the directory wasn't setup for EB and that I should run eb init. doing so generate a new config.yml file inside .elasticbeanstalk and it ignores my zip deployment (even if I add the dploy command to the new config file). Is this method still relevant? if so what am I doing wrong?